# Events or functions on javascript class

Tags: node.js

I'm using `EventEmitter` in some classes, but i'm really confused whether event listening and events emitting are more efficient than calling object methods?

I want the object to be able to listen for a number of events that are emitted to it, and also  emit a number of events to the object that originally emitted the events to the object and some others objects as well.

And i pretty much confused whether when should i use functions which in turn call other object methods and so on.

Comment: Don't use events when a simple function call can work in all situations. For a function call, the caller has to know what object is being called. If, sometimes, the emitter doesn't know (or can't know) which objects are listening, that is the case to use events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events improve module decoupling. It is all about this simple question: "How many files do I have to touch to modify or add feature X?"

A simple example: You have a web server, a logging module and a starting script, which ties both together on startup. The function call way looks like this:

```
// Startup.js
var Startup = function() {
    var logger = new Logger();
    var server = new Server(logger);
};

// Logger.js
var Logger = function() {
};
Logger.prototype.log = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};

// Server.js
var Server = function(logger) {
    this.logger = logger;
};
Server.prototype.start() {
    this.logger.log("Start server...");
};
```

You can see that Startup knows all classes and Server knows about logger and how to use it. If I want to rename Logger's function log to write I have to touch Logger and Server.

Now let's have a look at a event driven approach:

```
// Startup.js
var Startup = function() {
    var logger = new Logger();
    var server = new Server();
    server.addListener(logger);
};

// Logger.js
var Logger = function() {
    this.on("startup", function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });
};
Logger.prototype.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;

// Server.js
var Server = function() {
};
Server.prototype.start() {
    this.emit("startup", "Start server...");
};
Server.prototype.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;
```

Now Logger and Server don't know each other. I can rename log and all I have to touch is Logger.js. I can even remove Logger or add more Loggers, all of them working with Server. But I never have to touch Server.js.

This is a simple example and decoupling doen't look important here. But the larger a project gets, the more benefits come up.

You can Unit-Test Server without having to mock Logger. And Logger is only one dependency. Imagine the advantage if Server had five or more submodules you have to simulate.

I hope this helps you to understand the benefits of event driven architectures.